# How to load incremental data into fact table when source table don't have timestamp and Unique Key

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

I have a transaction table having about 400 million rows in source. It don't have timestamp and unique key columns. It have only `Bill_month` and `Bill_Year` columns.

For loading this table into staging I have added a new datetime column by adding default bill_date as 01.

- First we delete last 3 month data from staging tables.
- Get last 3 months data from source table.
- Load that 3 months data from source to staging table.

We do this because we only get update for last three months data.

Now I have to include this transaction table as Fact table. What will be the best practice for loading the fact table by picking data from the staging table?  Also we have to look up with dimensions for Foreign Keys.

- Should I implement the same method I have used for loading to the staging table?

Comment: Bear in mind that the word "crore" isn't widely known in e.g. the US, UK, Australia, etc. (If you were wondering, folks, a crore is 10,000,000)

Comment: @MattGibson It was a bit puzzling how 40 rows with a typo could pose a  problem.

Comment: Is there some reason you think you need to do something different because it's a fact table?   Is there some need that your current implementation will not meet?